# SQL - Recieve sum of results in different months

Tags: sql, t-sql, sum, union

Im trying to receive sum of hours that employees has reported a specific reason during each month in the year.

For example:

```
CostCentre | January | February | March | April etc.
```

Im trying to do like:

```
Select Costcentre, sum(hours), '00.00', '00.00'
From Transaction
Where Fromdate between first of @January AND Last of @January

Group by costcentre


Union

Select Costcentre,'00.00', sum(hours), '00.00'
From Transaction
Where Fromdate between first of @February AND Last of @February
Group by costcentre
```

I want the record to be depending on when i run the report, so i cannot use specific dates or years.

Im self taught in SQL and been doing this for 1 year, so my google skills isn't the best since i don't really understand 100%.

I was trying to follow this guide without success:
http://zarez.net/?p=2971

Comment: I really don't follow what you are asking here. Also `Fromdate between first of @February AND Last of @February` is *not* valid T-SQL. Consumable (**not** images) sample data and expected results will very likely help us help you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this bit - *"I want the record to be depending on when i run the report, so i cannot use specific dates or years"* please? e.g. what results do you want when running the report in August, and how and why does this differ from the results you want when running the report in January? My early advice would be though to simply return the raw data as simply as possible from Excel (e.g. 3 columns, Cost Centre, 1st of the month and the number of hours), then let your presentation layer worry about the formatting

Comment: Hi @Robin in order to clear the objective can you add a table structure or an expected result to the question?

That way others can understand what you are trying to achieve with the query.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select Costcentre,
      sum(case when month(fromdate) = 1 then hours else 0 end) as jan,
      sum(case when month(fromdate) = 2 then hours else 0 end) as feb,
      . . . 
From Transaction
Where year(Fromdate) = year(getdate());
```

Or:

```
where fromdate >= datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1, 1) and
      fromdate < datefromparts(year(getdate()) + 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, man, I will try and see if it works. Look promising tho!